# Why can't my client (instant messager) connect to my server (instant messager)?

Tags: java, jframe, client, server

I am watching tutorials where the guy builds an instant messager, but somewhere I messed up and I can't figure out what I did wrong. Here is my code...

Server Main Class:

```
    Server GUI = new Server();
    GUI.startRunning();
   }
}
```

Server Class:

```
private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;

// constructor
public Server() {
    super("HPIM");
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false);
    userText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
            userText.setText("");
        }

    });
    add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    chatWindow.setEditable(false);
    add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(300, 150);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

// set up and run the server
public void startRunning() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
        while (true) {
            try {
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
                whileChatting();
            } catch (EOFException eofException) {
                showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
            } finally {
                closeCrap();
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// wait for connection, then display connection information
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
    showMessage(" Waiting for someone to connect... \n");
    connection = server.accept();
    showMessage(" Now connected to "
            + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

// get stream to send and receive data
private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();

    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

    showMessage("\n The streams are now setup. \n");
}

// during the chat conversation
private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
    String message = "You are now connected!";
    sendMessage(message);
    ableToType(true);
    do {
        try {
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
            showMessage("\n Not sure what that user sent");
        }
    } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
}

// close streams and sockets after you are done chatting
private void closeCrap() {
    showMessage("\n Closing connections... \n");
    ableToType(false);
    try {
        input.close();
        output.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// send message to client
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    try {
        output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\n SERVER - " + message);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: CAN NOT SEND MESSAGE");
    }
}

// updates chat window
private void showMessage(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            chatWindow.append(text);
        }

    });
}

// let the user type stuff into their box
public void ableToType(final boolean TOF) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            userText.setEditable(TOF);
        }
    });
  }

}
```

Client Main Class:

```
Client client;
client = new Client("127.0.0.1");
client.startRunning();
 }
}
```

Client Class:

```
private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private String message = "";
private String serverIP;
private Socket connection;

// constructor
public Client(String host) {
    super("HPIM Client");
    serverIP = host;
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false);
    userText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
            userText.setText("");
        }

    });
    add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(300, 150);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

// connect to server
public void startRunning() {
    try {
        connectToServer();
        whileChatting();
        setupStreams();
    } catch (EOFException eofException) {
        showMessage("\nClient terminated connection");
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeCrap();
    }
}

// connect to server
private void connectToServer() throws IOException {
    showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
    showMessage("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

// set up streams and receive messages
private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    showMessage("\nStreams are set up \n");
}

// while chatting with server
private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
    ableToType(true);
    do {
        try {
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
            showMessage("\nNot sure what you sent");
        }
    } while (!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
}

// close the streams and sockets
private void closeCrap() {
    showMessage("\nTerminating connection");
    ableToType(false);
    try {
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// send messages to server
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    try {
        output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nCLIENT - " + message);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        chatWindow.append("\nCouldn't send message!");
    }
}

// change/update chatWindow
private void showMessage(final String m) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            chatWindow.append(m);
        }

    });



}

// gives or takes away permission to type in userText
private void ableToType(final boolean TOF){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            userText.setEditable(TOF);
        }

    });
  }


}
```

Comment: You may want to consider actually telling us what this code does in reality, and how that differs from what you expect. You may also want to consider reading up on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or how to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and sorry for not explaining. First here is the explanation... What it does is the client instant messager connects to the server instant messager on a local host, and then you can communicate with each other until one user ends the application by closing it or sending the message "END". 
Here is the answer...
What I did wrong was in the client side I didn't but a while loop in the start running method.